# For loop crashes program while trying to read array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Exercise: The vector A[1 to N] and a value s is given. Build the program that writes backwards every group of s elements. If s divided by N has a remainder, then the remaining values should be unchanged. If s is bigger than N (the nr of elements of the vector) than there will be no modification.

Lets say s = 4 and  A = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)then after execution the values will be A = (4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5)

My teacher requires this kind of vector: int n, A[n] where n is a value given by the user. And i think this is what is causing my program to crash when i read the final values. If not, where is the problem?

```
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int ordering(int s, int n, int A[]);

int main()
{
    int n, A[n];
    int s;
    cout << "Vlera e s: ";
    cin >> s;

    if (s <= 0) 
    {
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "\nN: ";
    cin >> n;

    if (n <= 0) 
    {
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "\nVector:";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        A[i] = i + 1;
        cout << " " << A[i] << " ";
    }

    if (s > n)
    {
        cout << "\nNo change\n";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ordering(s, n, A);
    }

    cout << "\nNew vector:";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << " " << A[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}

int ordering(int s, int n, int A[])
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0, divider = n / s; i < divider; i++)
    {
        int decrease = 0;
        for (int j = counter, a = counter + s; j < a; j++)
        {
            A[j] = a - decrease;
            decrease++;
        }
        counter += s;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A[n] is not valid c++.  C++ requires that array sizes be compile-time constants.

Comment: And even if you enable variable-length arrays through compiler extensions, `n` is uninitialized so that allocation is malformed.

Comment: `int n, A[n];` -- If your compiler didn't allow this non-standard syntax, how would you have solved the problem?  It seems `g++` issues generate a bulk of a lot of questions here.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Exactly! I told my teacher just that, that it doesnt compile and she told me to use dev c++ where it compiles. I wrote the same code but using vector instead and the output is correct. She insists i use A[n] and im stuck with this version

Comment: Your teacher should be at worst fired, or at best, teach another programming language, not C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the compiler in dev c++ allows it

Comment: Then you're not learning C++, plain and simple.  And it won't compile in devC++ (which really uses g++ under the hood), if you turn on the ANSI compiler switches.  Maybe your teacher should get the free Visual Studio Community 2019 compiler for a reality check.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That is the one i personally use and she told me not to. She keeps insisting that we only use this kind of array and i dont know. I will just turn the assignment in this way i guess

Comment: @Bryar I used dev-c++ in 2004 and had the same bug since before.

Comment: @Bryar. Please give your teacher this link [arrays](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) where the permitted expression is defined on line 3 so she she doesn't have to read very far. To be helpful she can click the link to get a complete definition of what that means and on line 1 of that definition it states "an expression that can be evaluated at compile time". So she has to read to line three and click one link if she doesn't get it.

Comment: @Bryar as PaulMcKenzie said your teacher is out of reality. Just do the assignment but never think what you're going to learn is what C++ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing variable as array size is not valid you need to use constant `const int n` or create dinamic array `int* arr = new int[n];`, that array will be created in runtime, and you can pass variable as it size. Dont forget to delete that array whet it goes out of scope `delete[] arr;`

Answer (score 3):

This program using a compiler extension to allow variable sized arrays in the form `myArray[variableSize]`. Whilst not standard, it does work on some compilers.

You are using this feature here:

```
int n, A[n];
```

However, `n` is uninitialised at this point. This is undefined behaviour even on the compilers that support such variable sized arrays. One possible (but not the only) outcome of undefined behaviour is your program crashing.

Undefined behaviour can do anything in theory, but the realistic set of things in can do in reality is smaller. Some of the likely implications of the undefined behaviour here:

1. `n` has some huge number in it, from whatever last used that bit of memory. As a result, `A` is huge.
2. `n` is 0. You can't have a 0 sized array. If the compiler doesn't notice this, you could end up trashing memory.
3. Since `n` is uninitialised, the optimiser for the compiler (they usually do very some optimisations, even when on -O0) assumes that undefined behaviour cannot occur, which is violated here, leading to strange behaviour.
4. `n` is a reasonable value, just by luck, but because it is later updated it no longer matches the size of the array and you end up reading / writing memory off the end of the array, trashing memory.

There are other possibilities, but this gives an idea of the kind of things that can happen as a result of this specific instance of undefined behaviour. If you're interested to know more, using a debugger to step through the code in assembly (you only need learn a little to understand the output, it looks more scary than it need be) will show you what's actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

Variable length arrays is not a standard C++ feature.

```
int n, A[n];
```

Moreover in the above declaration the variable n was not initialized. So in any case the program has undefined behavior.

Instead of an array you could use the standard class template `std::vector`.

The program can look simpler and more safer is to use standard algorithms such as, for example, `std::reverse`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

void reorder( std::vector<int> &v, size_t s )
{
    if ( not ( s < 2 ) )
    {
        for ( auto last = std::end( v ); 
              not (std::distance( std::begin( v ), last ) < s );  )
        {
            auto first = std::prev( last, s );
            std::reverse( first, last );
            last = first;
        }
    }       
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "Vlera e s: ";

    size_t s = 0;
    std::cin >> s;

    std::cout << "N: ";

    size_t n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<int> v( n );

    std::iota( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), 1 );

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    reorder( v, s );

    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Vlera e s: 4
N: 10

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 6 5 4 3 10 9 8 7
```

But it seems you need write the corresponding code yourself using loops. In this case the program can look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void reorder( std::vector<int> &v, size_t s )
{
    if ( not ( s < 2 ) )
    {
        for ( auto n = v.size(); !( n < s ); n -= s )
        {
            for ( size_t i = 0; i < s / 2; i++ )
            {
                int value = v[n - s + i];
                v[n - s + i] = v[n - i - 1];
                v[n - i - 1] = value;
            }
        }
    }       
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "Vlera e s: ";

    size_t s = 0;
    std::cin >> s;

    std::cout << "N: ";

    size_t n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<int> v( n );

    int value = 1;

    for ( auto &item : v ) item = value++; 

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    reorder( v, s );

    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look as already shown above

```
Vlera e s: 4
N: 10

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 6 5 4 3 10 9 8 7
```